# Set message is not showing up when message id has repeating digits at the end

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

So I'm working on a bot that says "Checked and witnessed." when the id of a message ends with repeating digits (eg. 11, 22). The odd thing is that this message does not show up, even if a message ID **does** have repeating digits at the end.

```
        var id = message.id;
        const dubs = RegExp('(\d)\1+$');
        if(dubs.test(id)) {
            message.channel.send("Checked and witnessed. " + id);
        } else {
            message.channel.send("Well shoot, that wasn't dubs. Try rolling again. (" + id + ")");
        }
```

[image: "Well shoot, that wasn't dubs. Try rolling again." showing up despite the message id ending with repeating digits.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will work:

```js
        var id = message.id;
        const dubs = /(\d)\1+$/;
        if(dubs.test(id)) {
            message.channel.send("Checked and witnessed. " + id);
        } else {
            message.channel.send("Well shoot, that wasn't dubs. Try rolling again. (" + id + ")");
        }
```